# Cin from stdin when it his the end of a line

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a file for example

```
M
4
2
//comments
.#..
```

It is given to the program via stdin. I can't use fstream, just iostream.

If I want to read the whole thing character by character could I do?

```
char first_letter, first_num, second_num;
cin >> first_letter;
cin >> first_num;
cin >> second_num;
```

Or would the end of the line mess up cin? As in, does cin know after it reads M for first_letter, that it needs to go to the end line?

Secondly I dont want to read the comment lines. My plan is that if I see a / I will use getline to "trash" the line then move to the . # . . and store those in my array. Would that be the best way to do that?

Comment: `cin >> x` skips leading whitespace. Watch out if you mix that with `getline`, though. They have a difference in what they leave in the buffer.

Comment: Skips leading whitespace meaning that it would go down to next line without a problem correct? 

And for buffer since I've never heard that word in class I don't think I need to worry about that. So I think I should be good there

Thank you

Comment: Well, all I have to say then is to please read some of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getline+skipping) before asking your very probable next question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, streams skip whitespace (space, tabs, newlines) by default, so that part is easy.

Now, concerning the comment lines, this is a bit more complicated. You can use std::getline() to read one line. This will store the line in a string and discard the trailing newline. However, if you e.g. read the first letter in your code above, the newline remains in the stream, so getline() will read an empty string. In short, don't mix line-based and token-based input.

In practice, you read a line and either parse the it manually or you create a stream for that:

```
while(getline(in, line)) {
    if(line.empty()) continue; // empty line
    if(line[0] == '#') continue; // comment line
    // parse line
    std::stringstream s(line);
    char c;
    s >> c;
}
```